# getAdapterPosition returns me NO_POSITION, returns actual (adapterposition - 1)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i am using Retrofit to get json and i am putting in Room database.
Then, i use recyclerview to show data. But first EVER time i've stucked in a problem , when getadApterPositoin() returns me NO_POSITION OR ( ACTUAL adapter position - 1).
I've read a lot articles , but i am still confused, how to fix it. If any code needed, please mention.
ViewHolder code

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_main_photo);
            image.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    Log.e("adapter", "No position if statement");
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("adapter", "POSITION else statement");
                }
//                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PictureInfoPage.class);
//                intent.putExtra("position", getAdapterPosition());
                Log.e("MainPageAdapter", getAdapterPosition() + "");
//                context.startActivity(intent);
            });
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain me , what is wrong, where am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your condition, change it to:

```
 if (pos == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                Log.e("adapter", "No position if statement");
            }
            else {
                Log.e("adapter", "POSITION else statement");
```

because pos is getting correctly but RecyclerView.NO_POSITION returns -1, so you see wrong result.